# How can I find list of Guice modules in my web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, module, guice

I've a web application that uses Guice heavily. I created a module and followed all the Guice guidelines to package it and put it in web-inf/lib directory and our own also custom API. However, my module is not found by the web app and I get nullpointer error. I was wondering if there is any way to find list Guice modules deployed and injected in my web application to see if mine is listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use logging in your module

```
package stackoverflowscrapbook;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyModule.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        LOG.info("Initialising MyModule");
        // rest of the configuration here
    }
}
```

The following simple test

```
package stackoverflowscrapbook;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.inject.Guice;

public class TestMyModule {

    @Test
    public void testDependencyInjection(){
         Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    }
}
```

Produces the output below

```
 Jan 18, 2017 9:51:04 PM stackoverflowscrapbook.MyModule configure
 INFO: Initialising MyModule
```

Obviously, you can choose a different logging framework I used JUL just because it is available on the JDK and also a different level of logging granularity.

Comment: I did this, but I did not see the log line, any other idea?

Comment: That seems to confirm your suspects: your module is not being installed.